# White in unity isnt white but beige

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've finally decided to start Unity. I have little to none experience with these kinds of stuff, and I'm currently facing a problem. When I import a 3d shape on unity, the default color is beige, even though it is set to white. When I try making a white texture and apply it to the object, it still turns out as beige.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to lighting. Check the light source in your scene, it probably has a yellow-ish color, try to turn that back to white. 
Depending on your render pipeline (Universal RP, HDRP...) you might even have something like global illumination with a slight color tint enabled. Try to check your lighting settings.

You can also always click on the material the object in question uses and in the little preview window you see it lit by a neutral light source, without your scene lighting settings.

also, you did not provide an image, which is why I can only help you so far given your message :)